# Casting with multiple inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, casting, multiple-inheritance

The following code does not compile, and `gcc -std=c++11` says it is an invalid static cast:

```
class A { public: virtual ~A() {} };
class B { public: virtual ~B() {} };
class AD : public A { public: virtual ~AD() {} };

class AB : public B, public A {};
class ADB : public B, public AD {};

int main() {
    ADB adb;
    ADB* ptr = &adb;
    AB* cast = static_cast<AB*>(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

I would like to cast a class of type `ADB` to `AB`. This *feels* like it should be safe to do - after all, the memory structure of `ADB` is `B` followed by `AD`, which itself is just `A` followed by `AD`'s own members. Thus it would seem that literally forcing compiler to interpret the pointer `ptr` as an `AB` would always be defined:

```
class A { public: virtual ~A() {} };
class B { public: virtual ~B() {} };
class AD : public A { public: virtual ~AD() {} };

class AB : public B, public A {};
class ADB : public B, public AD {};

int main() {
    ADB adb;
    ADB* ptr = &adb;
    AB* cast = reinterpret_cast<AB*>(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

This does not compile either, resulting in the linker complaining about undefined references
to the vtable and to `operator delete(void*)`.

So clearly at some point the vtable pointers are not "syncing up" when casted, in which case I somehow need to cast the individual base class of `AD` of `ADB` to just the `A` of `AB`. I'm not exactly sure about that, just guessing. How can I do this or something equivalent to it?

Comment: Being derived from the same types does not make them anything but distantly related, not enough for static cast.

Comment: @StephaneRolland I know. I didn't say it did...

Comment: Basically, don't do this. This looks like an XY problem. Tell us what you actually want to accomplish, and maybe we can tell you a better way.

Comment: @Brian well, I was trying to abstract the problem, in essence I'm making a class which carries some data and a templated type `T`. In order to avoid overhead, I'd be nice to store a `struct { meta m; T t; }`, the pointer for which which would be contained `mytype<T>`. But in order to allow casting from `mytype<T>` to `mytype<TBase>`, I am instead storing a pointer to a `struct stored : public meta, public T`, in hopes of accomplishing what's in my question.

Comment: @StephaneRolland I apologize for being unclear. My what I meant to say is cast a class of type `ADB` to `AB`, but I wanted to convey the structure of the types in memory.

Comment: @StephaneRolland That may indeed be the case, which is why I'd appreciate your help. Hopefully my comment for user Brian provides some context.

Comment: The memory ordering of base classes is at the discretion of the implementation. Also, even if the ordering is left to right, there may be padding between B and AD, so the memory layout is actually "B followed by padding followed by A".

Comment: @RaymondChen Still, the compiler has all the information necessary to implement such a cross inheritance cast, and it would be able to do so at compile time. Anyways, I came up with the solution to mimic this behavior anyway.

Comment: It would have to have psychic powers to know that somebody in another translation unit will try this trick and intentionally pad the AB class suboptimally to allow it. Either that or it pads AB suboptimally even if the trick is never used.

Comment: @Raymond Chen What do you mean by "pad suboptimally?" If I'm understanding correctly, as gcc is right now, it would be `|-----B-----|(potentially padding|-----A-----|(potentially padding)|-----AD's extension----|`. The only thing that would have to change is how `static_cast` works in the case of multiple hierarchies, which would just take some extra time during compilation. But this is a moot point anyway.

Comment: gcc is not the only compiler and VAX is not the only CPU architecture. The standard must support all compilers, not just gcc. Other compilers may have to pad differently due to the way they implement virtual destructors or specific characteristics of the target architecture.

Comment: @RaymondChen then other compilers would just have different static cast implementations, which is fine.

Comment: But you are now requiring other compilers to pad suboptimally and otherwise change their design *just in case* somebody tries to do something *that isn't even allowed by the standard in the first place*.

Comment: @RaymondChen (Btw I'm not arguing just for the sake of it, I understand that a nonstandard feature like this shouldn't be implemented) I genuinely do not understand where this "sub-optimal padding" would be necessary. It would seem that all that would change is perhaps during _the compilation of_ a `static_cast`, the compiler would need to detect that we're making a cross-hierarchy cast (and since it has to traverse the tree anyway, this wouldn't be too bad), and then just change the address shift that the static cast uses to get the pointer it returns, no?

Comment: Suppose `A` and `B` are each 4 bytes long and require 8-byte alignment, and `AD` is 8 bytes long and requires 16-byte alignment. `ADB` consists of a `B`, 12 bytes of padding, then an `AD`. How do you lay out `AB`? Option 1: Place `B`, then 4 bytes of padding, then an `A`. But the first `sizeof(AB)` bytes of `ADB` are not an `AB`, so the sneaky cast doesn't work. Option 2: Place `B`, then 12 bytes of padding, then an `A`. Now, the first `sizeof(AB)` bytes of `ADB` match the layout of an `AB`, but it also wastes 8 bytes of memory to guard against something that is technically illegal anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only successfully cast between classes which are in the object's inheritance structure. So, you can cast an ADB to an A, a B, or an AD. Your rationalization of similar memory layouts does not apply. While an understanding of the underlying implementation can offer helpful insights into certain "how"s and "why"s (especially when it comes to performance), you should not ever have to consider the underlying implementation to understand (or rationalize) the rules of language features. It works the way it does to help you express higher-level intent.

More importantly, you should never circumvent restrictions built in to the language based on exploited knowledge of the underlying implementation. While there may be occasional valid cases to do so, most of the time, it will result in non-portable code or code that doesn't survive an update of the compiler - failing to compile or breaking mysteriously in production.

Anyway, your assumption about memory layout may be incorrect; defining the virtual destructors is forcing the compiler to inject vtable pointers into the memory layouts of A,B, and AD, so the actual memory layout of an ADB may not be what you think it is.

Comment: Ah, ok, so it's the virtual destructors then! That's the explanation I was looking for. Let me test that that's actually the case.

Comment: Just tested it by removing them, and now it compiles fine! Obviously, without the virtual destructors it can only use nontrivial destruction, and forcing the `reinterpret_cast` is nonstandard anyway (because it assumes the memory layout is as I described it above, which it doesn't have to be), but at least it all makes sense now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cast an `AB`, a static_cast could only cast an `AB` to a `B` or an `A`. That's all.

This is the guaranty that offers `static_cast` at compilation time: It only allows cast operations that are **logically** ok, between types that are related.

You could also imagine these static_cast, and they would be ok:

- an A in AD
- a B or an A in AB
- a B or an AD in ADB
- an A in ADB

But there is NO path in the inheritance hierarchy between AB and ADB to do what you want. In no way AB and ADB are related types.

Comment: Why aren't they related? How is `ADB` not just `AB` with `AD`'s vtable pointer and members appended to it?

Comment: `class AB : public B, public A {};` class AB is only related to B and A. That's why it's unrelated to ADB.

Comment: OK, I understand why it doesn't work according to the standard now, thanks. But do you agree that at the bit level, there doesn't seem to be a problem with the cast? That's what I'm not understanding - what's wrong with the `reinterpret_cast`?